# cant view image that I downloaded using aws-sdk and wrote to disk using node

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-sdk-js

Im downloading an image (.png file) on my express server from an `s3` bucket using the `aws-sdk` for node and then writing it to the disk using  `fs.writeFileSync`.
the problem is  when I try to view the image on my computer, it says:
`is appears that we dont support this file format.`
I checked properties of the downloaded images and its 37.2 KB so it means something was returned.

Is this not the correct way to download the image?

here is my code:

```
function downloadFile(fileKey) {
  const downloadParams = {
    Key: fileKey,
    Bucket: bucketName,
  };
  return s3.getObject(downloadParams).promise();
}


router.get("/getImage", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let image= await downloadFile(`${req.query.imageID}.png`);
    fs.writeFileSync(`Images/${req.query.image}.png`, image);

    res.status(200).send();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(500).send(e);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was that I writing the full `s3 result` to the disk(`image`) and not the `Body` from the  `result`.
this is the correct code:

```
 fs.writeFileSync(`Images/${req.query.taskID}-plot.png`, image.Body);
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code please make sure you passed the correct parameter to fs.writeFileAsync. as I can see `plot` instead of the `image`.

second please make sure to download the image directly from the s3 and make sure you are able to view it on your computer if not you have to add the `'Content-Type': 'image/png'` while uploading the image to s3.

Comment: sorry,I corrected the parameter to `image` ,I tried downloading directly from the s3 bucket and I am able to view it on my computer.